# Aws lambda function in java(spring boot) could not create a file?

Tags: java, spring-boot, aws-lambda

```
 bool = tempFile.createNewFile();
```

the above line of code throwing java.io.IOException: Read-only file system,
we are trying to create a file in aws lambda function(java spring boot)  but we could not create a file?

Comment: Are you using the result of `createNewFile` for some sort of flag or inter-thread communication?

Comment: We are using it's result for just checking weather the file is created or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To make sure your file goes where you want in the Lambda environment you could create the file like:

```
File tempFile = File.createTempFile("tmp", null, new File("/tmp"));
```

However, this does *not* do exactly what `createNewFile()` does in that it will not check if a file of the same name already exists.  If that is required (and I'd question that design in a Lambda environment) then this won't be a direct replacement.

**EDIT**

It sounds like you're just trying to create a file.  So instead of a using `createTempFile` just use something like:

```
File newFile = new File("/tmp/rose.jpeg");
boolean created = newFile.createNewFile();
```

Comment: We are creating a file name like rose with extension .jpeg, the file is created using above method just fine but it is created as rose7365283892685952111.jpeg , some random number gets attached to the file name, how to eliminate that random number

```
File tempFile = null;

String ="rose.jpeg";

String filename = attachment_file.split("\\.")[0]; 

String extension = attachment_file.split("\\.")[1];

tempFile  = File.createTempFile(filename,"."+extension, new File("/tmp"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can use `/tmp` folder for storing files, just keep in mind that it will be deleted once the Lambda instance will be terminated. Also there is a 500mb limit.

What path are you using to save the file?

Comment: /tmp is the path, the below code just works fine but some random number gets appended to file name , if rose is file name output is like rose412568789544

File tempFile = null;

String ="rose.jpeg";

String filename = attachment_file.split("\\.")[0]; 

String extension = attachment_file.split("\\.")[1];

tempFile  = File.createTempFile(filename,"."+extension, new File("/tmp"));

Comment: createTempFile creates a temporary file (adding the random). Use File.createNewFile()  if you want to remove that random from the name.

Comment: if we use createNewFile in aws lamba function it is throwing  java.io.IOException: Read-only file system.

Answer (score 0):

`aws-lambda` is `serverless`, you cannot create files on lambda.  You have have to create an s3 and explicitly pass the path to the file.

Comment: This is not correct.  Temporary files can be created in `/tmp`.

Comment: you're right, as long as the file created is a temporary file, used only for the length of the execution of the lambda function.  If you want any level of persistence for the file beyond the execution, it is recommended to use S3 or any other storage means.